# 502 Bad Gateway Plesk vhost changes

Tags: php, nginx, plesk, opayo

I am having some trouble with an eCommerce site, which is using SagePay as the payment gateway. Some payments are being completed, others are not, and the error that seems to be coming up for users is either an Internal Server Error, or 502 Bad Gateway Error.

I have looked into the Server Logs (specifically proxy_error_log) and found that each transaction that is failing is showing an error in the logs as follows:

2014/12/02 04:24:11 [error] 9179#0: *70668 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream...

After doing a bit of digging, I found that supposedly editing the proxy buffer size seems to fix it. I have added the following code to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;
```

The second step is to add another block of code to the location ~ .php$ {} block in the vhost file:

```
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
```

However the vhost file contains the following text:

ATTENTION!

DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE BECAUSE IT WAS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY,
SO ALL YOUR CHANGES WILL BE LOST THE NEXT TIME THE FILE IS GENERATED.

Any idea why it says this, and is there a way to get around it?!

Comment: What version of Plesk are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Plesk 11 you can add extra nginx directives per vhost through the Plesk panel.

Go to Domains > example.co.uk > Web Server Settings.

At the bottom of this page is a textarea labelled "Additional nginx directives" where you can just drop in your directives. Click OK and Plesk will restart the web server and the directives will be in effect

To add the fastcgi directives within the php location block you'd need to do add something like this to the additional nginx directives textarea:

```
proxy_buffer_size   128k;
proxy_buffers   4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

location ~ .php$ {
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
}
```

Comment: It's the fastcgi ones that I want to add, so is this where I would add them? And if so, is there a specific format that I have to paste that block of code in like, as supposedly it is meant to go inside a certain  location ~ .php$ {} block which is meant to be location the vhosts file...?

Comment: ~ .php$ {} is a location match directive. So whatever it is you've read is suggesting to only add those fastcgi values for .php files. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Okay thats great cheers, I will add this into the Additional nginx directives field now and see if it fixes the bug!

Comment: Cool :) Care to accept the answer if you think it's good enough?

Comment: Have just gone to try and access the CMS on the site, http://.../admin.php/ and instead of executing the url, it is downloading it?! Seems to be doing it with all .php files on the site now. Guessing this is something to do with this?

Comment: What happens if you remove the location ~ .php$ { line and the ending } so the fastcgi directives are not within a location block? Your PHP files aren't being passed to the PHP engine.

Comment: That has fixed it now, can access .php files again. But will it matter that the code isn't being put into that block? I'm not very well up on all this nginx stuff!